# Post telephone interview blues

Tags: interviewing

I had an unexpected phone interview. This phone call took place after the first phase of the interview which I passed.

I stupidly agreed to take the call even thought the time and place wasn't suitable for me. They asked me what I understood of the job and whether I had studied and worked before in which I said yes that I have done it before.

Looking back I don't feel fully justified my experience. I am thinking of calling them back to fully justify my case. How could I approach this without damaging my application?

Comment: As the saying goes, no second chance to make a first impression.  Calling them back would be unproductive and more likely damaging than just letting it sit and see what happens.

Comment: @JaneS Unless you think this is off-topic (it's borderline), that should probably be an answer.

Comment: @Lilienthal I'm sure this is a dupe, but I didn't go hunting for it to verify, so I didn't leave a formal answer.

Comment: Their process probably includes the element of surprise in the interview. So you did your best, and I expect the other candidates to have been surprised as well.

Answer (score 3):

To be perfectly honest with you, I really don't think phoning them back with the intention of improving your answers is a good idea at all. You would never do the same thing in a face-to-face interview, and it may do more damage to your application than good.

I do find it a little strange that the data/time of your telephone interview wasn't scheduled beforehand, which would have you an opportunity to prepare. Is it possible that you have just misinterpreted the phone call as an interview?

Comment: I was told an informal phone interview would be happening this week but I wasn't told the date and time. The interviewer said that the job is very demanding (trainee job) which involves working as well as going to Uni. I said that I have juggled work and my two masters before and I used time management and organisational skills to keep track of deadlines, other responsibilities, and my leisure time to ease off the stress. The lady seemed impressed so I hope that was enough.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers! My mum said that it was not a good idea to call back and it would backfire if I did.